# Unable to publish multiple static transformations using tf

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 10 static transformations. Each one is saved in a separate yaml file. I want to publish these transformations using `StaticTransformBroadcaster`. Please see the code snippet below-

```
def main():
    # create tf static transform broadcaster
    tf_broadcaster = tf2_ros.StaticTransformBroadcaster()

    for i in range(10):
        calibFile = str(i) + '_calibration.yaml'

        with open(calibFile, 'r') as f:
            params = yaml.load(f)

        static_transformStamped = TransformStamped()

        static_transformStamped.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        static_transformStamped.header.frame_id = params['parent']
        static_transformStamped.child_frame_id = params['child']

        static_transformStamped.transform.translation = params['trans']
        static_transformStamped.transform.rotation = params['rot']

        # publish static transformation
        tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(static_transformStamped)

    # infinite loop
    rospy.spin()
```

Iteratively I am reading each transform and then by using `tf`, I am trying to publish them. However, the above code doesn't work. It just publishes the last transform only.

**My objective is to publish all static transformations.** I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287469/unable-to-publish-multiple-static-transformations-using-tf/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you're running into a peculiarity / TF2 specific characteristic of static transform publishers. From #q261815:

> Since it's a latched topic it's recommended to only have one Static Transform Publisher per process.

> You can resolve this by sending multiple transforms at once via a single broadcaster.

> ```
> br.sendTransform([t,t2])
> ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try with the following piece of codes

```
import rospy
import roslib
import tf


def handle_transform(parent, child, tr):
    br.sendTransform((tr[0], tr[1], 0), tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, tr[2]), rospy.Time.now(), child,parent)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    
    rospy.init_node('tfpublisher', anonymous=True) #make node
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 5hz

    br = tf.TransformBroadcaster() 
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        handle_transform("base_link", "scans", [0,0,0])     
        
        rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
This seems to use `tf`, not `tf2`. Static transforms are handled differently between the two.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thank you very much. I upvoted your suggestion. However, it is better to use `StaticTransformBroadcaster` from `tf2`.